# Expectation with exponential random variable

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, self-learning, expectation, conditional-expectation

> If $X_i$, $i=1,2,3$ are independent exponential random variable with
>   rates $\lambda_i$, find $$E[\max(X_i) \mid X_1<X_2<X_3]$$

I really did not understand this exercise, because if $$X_1<X_2<X_3\Rightarrow X_3=\max(X_i)$$
right?

So it should not simply be
$$E[\max(X_i) \mid X_1<X_2<X_3]=E[X_3]$$
because the memorylessness?

**EDIT:**
Let $X_{(n)}$ the maximum
$$F_{X_{(n)}}=F_{X_1}(x)F_{X_2}(x)F_{X_3}(x)=(1-e^{-\lambda_1x})(1-e^{-\lambda_2x})(1-e^{-\lambda_3x})$$
$$=1-e^{-\lambda_2x}-e^{-\lambda_1x}+e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)x}-e^{-\lambda_3x}+e^{-(\lambda_2+\lambda_3)x}+e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_3)x}-e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3)x}$$
$$E[X_{(n)}]=\int_0^\infty 1-F_{X_{(n)}}dx$$
$$=\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda_2x}+e^{-\lambda_1x}-e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)x}+e^{-\lambda_3x}-e^{-(\lambda_2+\lambda_3)x}-e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_3)x}+e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3)x}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\lambda_2}+\frac{1}{\lambda_1}-\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}+\frac{1}{\lambda_3}-\frac{1}{\lambda_2+\lambda_3}-\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_3}+\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3}$$

I tried some simplifications, but could not get the answer

**EDIT:** The book answer is
$$E[\max(X_i) \mid X_1<X_2<X_3]=\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3}+\frac{1}{\lambda_2+\lambda_3}+\frac{1}{\lambda_3}$$

Comment: $\mathbb E[\max_i X_i \mid X_1 < X_2 < X_3]$ is a random variable, not a number.

Comment: It will be the expectation of the max, you wrote that down  but changed your mind.

Comment: If we are told that $X_1\lt X_2\lt X_3$, then we know that $X_3$ is the max. Nothing is added from knowing that $X_1\lt X_2$.  The distribution, and hence expectation, of the max is not hard to calculate, find the cdf of the max.

Comment: I will have to rethink the $X_2$ doesn't matter.

Comment: the desired quantity is equal to $$\frac{\mathbb{E}\big( \max\{ X_1, X_2, X_3\} \cdot 1_{ (X_1 < X_2 < X_3)} \big) }{ \mathbb{P}(X_1 < X_2 < X_3)  } \cdot 1_{ (X_1 < X_2 < X_3)}  =\frac{\mathbb{E}\big(X_3 \cdot 1_{ (X_1 < X_2 < X_3)} \big) }{ \mathbb{P}(X_1 < X_2 < X_3)  } \cdot 1_{ (X_1 < X_2 < X_3)} $$ which is a random variable, not a deterministic number.

Comment: @Math1000: It is a number, since we're conditioning on a set, not a sigma-algebra.

Comment: @Chival: $\mathrm{E}[Y\mid A]=\mathrm{E}[Y\mathbf{1}_A]/P(A)$ for any event $A$ with $P(A)>0$. Hence you have an indicator function too much.

Comment: @StefanHansen - good point, $\{\omega\in\Omega : X_1(\omega) < X_2(\omega) < X_3(\omega)\}$ is an event, not a $\sigma$-algebra. So the conditional expectation is constant.

Comment: yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\mathsf E(\max_i X_i \mid X_1<X_2<X_3) = \mathsf E(X_3 \;\mathbf 1_{X_3>X_2>X_1})\big/ \mathsf P(X_3>X_2>X_1) \\
= \dfrac{\int_0^\infty \int_0^{x_3}\int_0^{x_2} x_3f_{X_3}(x_3)f_{X_2}(x_2)f_{X_1}(x_1)\operatorname d x_1 \operatorname d x_2\operatorname d x_3}{\int_0^\infty \int_0^{x_3}\int_0^{x_2} f_{X_3}(x_3)f_{X_2}(x_2)f_{X_1}(x_1)\operatorname d x_1 \operatorname d x_2\operatorname d x_3}$

Comment: I am still confused where to go from here. Will it be a good idea to literally compute the integral?